# How to download files from Google Cloud Storage using curl

Tags: curl, google-cloud-storage

For example this file: https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/_details/genomics-public-data/resources/broad/hg38/v0/Homo_sapiens_assembly38.fasta?pli=1

I'm trying to download this onto my server, which is accessed only via CLI, and when doing cURL on the Link URL, I just get HTML. Is there some direct link I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're making the request against the Cloud Console storage browser. You should instead make a request against the GCS API endpoint:

```
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/genomics-public-data/o/resources%2Fbroad%2Fhg38%2Fv0%2FHomo_sapiens_assembly38.fasta?alt=media
```

Note that you need to do URL escaping (like I did above) and also that if the object is not publicly readable you'll need to include an authorization header.

Comment: Thanks. Where did you get that link from?

Comment: The link corresponds to the [Cloud Storage API Endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints). What Mike did was just to add the path of the resource in the GCS bucket.

Comment: What Kevin said is correct. Note also that you need to include the alt=media query parameter, or else you'll get the object metadata instead of its content.